# Start a SPD 2013 workflow from custom action and then redirect to home page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a situation here where i need to start a 2013 workflow on an item with the help of custom action, everything works fine though when I click on custom action a new tab gets open to start the workflow and then it gets redirected to the default view of the list. I need to redirect it to the home page of the site or any other specific page.

Note: As it's a 2013 workflow, it doesn't have an initiation form and I am looking for a solution which doesn't involve infopath.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this, which is unfortunate.

Comment: As a matter of fact, when I trigger a workflow with a custom action (created in SPD 2013), once the workflow is done I am redirected back to the site home page, which I don't want. If I manually invoke the same workflow on an item in the list, I'm redirected to the default view of the list. My trouble is that I "*don't** want to be redirected back to the site's home page, but I do want to use a custom action button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem. I wanted to start the workflows but remain in the current view, and looking around the 'net I found this solution: https://plumsail.com/blog/2015/02/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-selected-items/

It shows you how to start a 2013 workflow with javascript after selecting the items. This example is mostly to select more than 1 item and run the workflow in all of them at once.

It was very useful for me. I didn't want it to allow users to select more than 1 item so I took out of the loop the action of calling the function that started the workflow.

Then in the part where the execution of the query is succesful after starting the workflow, you could add the window.location you desire, in this case to your home page.

Hope it helps to anyone.